# Click event on button menu appshell maui

Tags: shell, events, viewmodel, maui

I want to trigger an event when a user click on this button :

[image]

This displays a burger menu using an AppShell with MAUI.

There is the code of the AppShell :

```
<Shell
    x:Class="NoaMobileApp.AppShell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
    xmlns:Usersviews="clr-namespace:NoaMobileApp.Pages.UsersPages.TransportBB_Pages.View"
    xmlns:iconFont="clr-namespace:NoaMobileApp.Helpers.IconFont"
    xmlns:localization="clr-namespace:NoaMobileApp.Extensions.Localization"
    xmlns:models="clr-namespace:NoaMobileApp.Pages.Main_Pages.ViewModel"
    xmlns:views="clr-namespace:NoaMobileApp.Pages.Main_Pages.View"
    x:DataType="models:AppShellViewModel"
    NavigationPage.HasBackButton="False"
    NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False"
    Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Flyout"
    Shell.NavBarIsVisible="False"
    Shell.TabBarIsVisible="False">

   

    <Shell.FlyoutHeader>
        <StackLayout Padding="20">
            <Image
                Aspect="Fill"
                HeightRequest="100"
                Source="source.svg" />
            <Label
                FontAttributes="Bold"
                FontSize="Header"
                Text="{localization:Translate Hello}" />
            <Label
                x:Name="UserIDLabel"
                FontAttributes="Bold"
                FontSize="Subtitle"
                Text="{Binding Name}" />
        </StackLayout>
    </Shell.FlyoutHeader>

    <ShellContent
        Title="LoadingPage"
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:LoadingPage}"
        FlyoutItemIsVisible="False"
        NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False"
        Route="LoadingPage"
        Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Disabled"
        Shell.NavBarIsVisible="False" />
</Shell>
```

And the viewmodel :

```
public partial class AppShellViewModel : ObservableObject
    {

        [ObservableProperty]
        public string name = string.Empty;

        [RelayCommand]
        async void SignOut()
        {
            SecureStorage.Default.Remove("_authentificationToken");
            await AppShell.Current.GoToAsync($"//{nameof(LoginPage)}");
        }

    }
```

I tried to use the Appearing event but it is triggered when the app is launched

Any idea for this ?

Comment: May I know do you want to navigate to the LoginPage when clicking the hamburger icon?  As by design, when pressing the hamburger icon, or swiping from the left, displays the flyout. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/create